# PHP Thread telling to JavaScript that will sleep

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, multithreading, pthreads

The title is a little confuse, but my problem is:
Javascript do an AJAX Request to the PHP Controller. In the PHP Controller a Thread is created and started. The code is:

```
public function run() {
    while(true) {
        //Do Something...
        //Know I want to tell Javascript that I have done the thing and I'm going to sleep.
        sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

So the JavaScript code is:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: "controllers/DatabaseController/",
 data: dataObject,
 success: function(response) {
   //Do Something after the Thread Result
 }
});
```

I am thinking that this problem it's impossible... Because the Thread runs and sleep after a time set by the client. And when the Thread runs, the client side need to see the results of the Thread.

How can I do this? The Javascript need to be in a loop like the PHP Thread?

**The situation is:**
- Thread do polling of the equipments status and after that the javascript change the icons status (green or red) of the equipments.

Comment: This script will not finish, so the js success: call is never called. Maybe it's possible with an Ajax request todo something with partial data, i am not sure of that.

Comment: My suggestion is don`t let php code sleep just echo a sleep time number($sleeptime) and use setTimeout(fn,sleeptime) to request again.

Comment: he could also make a small server with php that holds the on off info for all equipment in assosiative array and then can quickly respond to all incoming ajax calls

Comment: Thanks for the support of all. @phper Can you explain better that setTimeout please?

Comment: @sietse85 I understand your point, but I need to simplify as most possible. I can't have another server. This is a small project for graduation

Comment: @BackSpace why you need  the thread sleep?

Comment: @phper The client set a time for the polling. So if the user set 10 seconds. The thread with do the polling of all equipments, and after 10 seconds will do it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
I used the javascript function setInterval with the time that user set, who runs a function that do an ajax request to the php controller.
The Controller create a thread that do the polling of the equipments and die.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

Create two controller methods: One to start the thread the other one to check the status of it.

You make your ajax request to start the thread. Once the thread is started, you return a response, with a success/error message.

If the thread was started successfully, you will then make a second ajax request periodically to check the status of the thread.

You may also, in the first call, return the expected time the thread will sleep so you can adjust the time which the second ajax request will be made.

**Edit** (trying to clarify):

Let's say that your thread will check how much fuel the machine has. That thread will query the machine and will save that into a database. 
The second method in the controller will query the database and fetch the results saved by the thread.

**Example**:

Controller:

```
class Controller
{
    public function startThread()
    {
        // start thread

        // return
    }

    public function checkStatus()
    {
        // query database for status

        // return results
    }

    public function thread()
    {
        // check for machines status

        // save the results into database
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: "controller/startThread/",
 data: dataObject,
 success: function(response) {
    // if success
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: "controller/checkStatus/",
         data: dataObject,
         success: function(response) {
            // your result will be here
         })
    }, 10000)
 }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the return response only come if the thread finished. If I sleep the thread, then the return response don't appear...

Comment: you don't wait for the thread to finish to return a response. You create the thread and return a response. Then you check the status of it with the second call.

Comment: Sorry but I am a little confused... The thread is created and started and return a response. So it means, that will do the 1st polling and return to javascript with success. The Javascript change the icons and what about the next iteration of thread? I'm not understanding what you mean with the "check the status of the thread". Sorry but I am newbie with PHP threads

Comment: Check the edit. See if the pseudo-code example helps.

Comment: I am looking at your answer and I appreciate, but I think that you are understanding wrong the problem. You start the thread and you check the status after the time that client set. But that time is not for that situation, the time is used to checkStatus again. So I have to send AJAX Request to start the thread and polling. When the polling is done, I tell the JS to do something with that results. When the time set goes, the method polling is called again... And the JS is called again... It's a loop working with time

Comment: Let's clarify then: Your thread will run every 10 secs and you want to check the status also every 10 secs, right?

Comment: Yeah, 10 secs is an example. It's the user that set the time.

Comment: I was thinking about Windows Schedule Task that execute the php file and the javascript file. But the problem is: The information of the panels to polling is inside an array that is a session variable. And in the command line, the session variables are empty

Comment: And if the user set 0 secs. The thread need to be stopped or killed